# Interrupt/stop thread with socket I/O blocking operation

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

At some point of my server application I want to stop some threads that are performing I/O blocking operations.

For instance, one of them have the following `run()` method:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("GWsocket thread running");

    int len;
    byte [] buffer = new byte[1500];
    try {
        this.in  = new DataInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
        this.out = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
        running = true;

        while (running){
            len = in.read (buffer);
            if (len < 0)
                running = false;
            else
                parsepacket (buffer, len);
        }

    }catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("GWsocket catch IOException: "+ex);
    }finally{
        try {
            System.out.println("Closing GWsocket");
            fireSocketClosure();
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("GWsocket finally IOException: "+ex);
        }
    }
}
```

If I Want to stop a thread running this code, what should I do?

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) they show how to do (**How do I stop a thread that waits for long periods (e.g., for input)?**), but I don't understand what they mean with:

> For this technique to work, it's critical that any method that catches
>   an interrupt exception and is not prepared to deal with it immediately
>   reasserts the exception. We say reasserts rather than rethrows,
>   because it is not always possible to rethrow the exception. If the
>   method that catches the InterruptedException is not declared to throw
>   this (checked) exception, then it should "reinterrupt itself" with the
>   following incantation: Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

Can anyone give me some hints? Some code examples would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution, described by Peter Lawrey and also seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method) is to close the socket.

With nio, You could also use a [SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) which is [interruptible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/InterruptibleChannel.html) and would allow the application of the [standard interrupt model of Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

A call to the [interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) method of your Thread object would throw an InterruptedException which would stop even your blocking IO operation.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a method like

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    this.socket.close();
}
```

and any blocking IO operations will throw a SocketException.

You might like to set a flag like `closed` which you can check if an exception thrown was to be expected or not.

BTW: You cannot be sure that you will get discrete packets on a read. It is far better to read what you need and use BufferedInputStream for efficiency.  Only read blocks if you don't need to parse the contents e.g. copying from a socket to a file.

e.g. your read could get just one byte or get the end of one packet and the start of another.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sometimes the `len = in.read (buffer);` gives me an IOException... Could be because I am using `DataInputStream` instead of `BufferedInputStream`?

Comment: Which stream you wrap it with makes no difference.