# How do I kill an instance of a class in another class?

Tags: java, instance, kill

I'm making a client-server application, in which the user can turn on or switch off the server from a gui; in order to let it work, I use a SwingWorker nested class. 
All seems to work correctly, but when I switch off the server and re-turn it on it doesn't work, probably because there is still another instance open of it that can't be overwritten: server is blocked on the accept() method.
I want to kill the previous instance when the user presses the switch off button, but I don't know how.

Here's the SwingWorker class that gives me problems:

```
class SwingWorkGUI extends SwingWorker
    {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
            int delay = 1000; 
            final Timer time = new Timer(delay, null);
            time.addActionListener( new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (Server.up == true){
                        upTimeMillis += 1000;
                        long diff = upTimeMillis/1000;
                        long numHrs = diff/60;
                        diff = diff%60;
                        long numMins = diff/60;
                        long numSecs = diff%60;
                        upTime.setText(numHrs + ":" + numMins + ":" + numSecs);
                    }
                    else {
                        upTime.setText("Server Actually Down");
                        time.stop();
                    }
                }           
            });
            time.start();
            mainServer = new Server();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Everytime the Turn On button is pressed, the actionPerformed determines whether the server is already on or not, then if not runs

```
SwingWorkGUI swg = new SwingWorkGUI(); 
swg.execute();
```

The execution blocks in the following instruction, but only the second (third,ecc.) time it is called:

```
mainServer = new Server();
```

Server.up is a static variable that helps me to kill the while(true) method in server.

How can I kill the open instance without closing all the application?

Comment: If you're running the server on a separate thread you can store a reference to that thread and call `interrupt()` on it and then clean up the reference to the server. This should cause the server to quit whatever it is doing. (You will probably also want to catch `InterruptedException`s on the `Server` and do some internal clean up as necessary).

Comment: Call `socket.close()` from an external thread to interrupt the `socket.accept()` method and then shutdown your server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem is that the `ServerSocket` object is blocked on the `accept()` call and you need to unblock it. Some options:

1. Call `ss.close()` from another thread (assumes `ss` is your `ServerSocket` object). This will make `accept()` throw a `SocketException`. Reference: [Javadocs for `ServerSocket.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29)
2. Create a new `Socket` from another thread and connect to your own server. This will unblock the `accept()` call. Now you can check your `Server.up` flag.
3. Set a timeout on your `ServerSocket`, e.g. 5 seconds. This will make `accept()` throw an `InterruptedIOException` on timeout. Reference: [Javadocs for `SO_TIMEOUT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_TIMEOUT)