# Thread blocked in accept

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket, multiplayer

I am making a multiplayer game using java sockets.  I have this code

```
class GetServer
{
    private boolean connected = false;
    private Socket s = null;

    public Socket createSocket(String name)
    {
        return createSocket(name, 55902);
    }

    private synchronized Socket createSocket(String serverName, int port)
    {
        receivingThread.start();

        try
        {
            DatagramSocket ss = new DatagramSocket();
            ss.setBroadcast(true);
            byte[] b = serverName.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);
            p.setAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {(byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255}));
            p.setPort(55902);

            while(!connected)
            {
                p.setData(b);
                ss.send(p);
            }

            return s;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void cancel()
    {
        connected = true;
    }

    private Thread receivingThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(55902);
                s = socket.accept();
                connected = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Which is a class that the server uses to connect to a client.  The idea is that createSocket is invoked with the name of the server and it will broadcast its name until a client tries to connect to it using the receiving thread.  However i also want to be able to cancel trying to connect to the client.  I added a cancel method which makes createSocket return null, however receivingThread is still blocked on accept.  How would i end the recievingThread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I interrupt a ServerSocket accept() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method)

Comment: A better protocol is to make the server listen for datagrampackets using `receive()` method. Then the client would broadcast looking for devices in the network. The server then reply back a datagrampacket to the client telling it "i'm here, you can connect to this port, and by the way this is my name"....etc

Comment: you need another thread to close the socket, this will cause throwing an exception to thread has blocked by some IO operation :)

Comment: accept() is for connection-oriented sockets like TCP, but you are doing a broadcast with the connectionless UDP instead. Note that if you want to wait for an incoming connection without blocking, you can use select().

Comment: Just FYI - Have you looked at Apache Mina? Its open source and used by lots of commercial socket based servers applications. It abstracts all the socket level details from you and is non-blocking.