# Java Server Socket Interrupt How to

Tags: java, serversocket

How can I stop a server socket which is listening client. My code look like below

```
 private ServerSocket serverSocket;

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    private BufferedReader input;
    public void run() {
    Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVE_LISTEN_RPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                try {

        this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                     String read = input.readLine();
                                 //Do something
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


             try {
              serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

I need to stop this thread when I got a command from another thread. I already sow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method) question but no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example how to close a socket from other thread:

```
private static volatile ServerSocket serverSocket;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    serverThread.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000); // wait a  bit, then close
    serverSocket.close();
}

static class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    private BufferedReader input;

    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(25);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                // client request handling logic
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: But I am getting an exception when closing serverSocket after accepting connection, I am doing this on android

Comment: Your code is neither synchronized and nor is your `ServerSocket` `volatile` - this is going to cause some horribly unpredictable race hazards.

Comment: @Haris, accept(...) by contract should either return a socket or throw an exception. In our case there's obviously no socket to return, so exception is thrown. My advice here is to simply ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

The server socket should be outside the `run()` method and should be *shared by the threads*.

Now when you need to interrupt the Thread which is calling `socket.accept()`, the other thread can call `socket.close()` and `accept()` will throw exception.