# Correct way to close ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm studying to use `ServerSocket` and get an error when trying to close `serverSocket` object while method `accept()` is working. Next I found solution with `setSoTimeout()` method. But I think ignore exception isn't best practice.
So, here's my two classes:

class **Server**:

```
public class Server {
    public static final int PORT = 8777;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private boolean serverRuns;

    Server() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            serverRuns = true;

            (new Control(this)).start(); // Takes commands while working
            while (serverRuns) {
                try {
                    serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                }
                catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    // cap
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
                System.out.println("Server stopped");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void stopServer() {
        serverRuns = false;
    }
    public boolean isServerRuns() {
        return serverRuns;
    }
    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Server s = new Server();
    }
}
```

class **Control**:

```
public class Control extends Thread {
    private Server activeServer;

    private Control() {}
    Control(Server activeServer) {
        this.activeServer = activeServer;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (activeServer.isServerRuns()) {
            String key = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            switch (key) {
                case "close":
                    activeServer.stopServer();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it correct way to terminate `ServerSocket` work(ignore exception and check `serverRuns` variable once a second)? Any recommendations are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the server close from an another Thread, cause `serverSocket.accept();` will be blocking

Take a look at: [Interrupt accept method and close the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method)

Comment: He's question was : "Is it correct way to terminate ServerSocket ?" Also i just add some arguments to tell "Yes it is" ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Xephi's answer:

> You need to call the server close from an another Thread

Well, one doesn't *need to* call `the ServerSocket.close()` from the other thread, but it certainly is an advisable approach.

> That is exactly what he is already doing. – user207421

No, it is not. What the OP is doing is to reset the `serverRuns` flag in the other thread and to periodically check this flag in the main `Server` thread with the aid of a socket timeout for the `accept()` call; I'd call that rather ugly.

With the recommended approach, the `Server` would be like:

```
    Server()
    {
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            (new Control(this)).start(); // Takes commands while working
            while (true)
            {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                …
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) { System.out.println("Server stopped"); }
          catch (IOException e)     { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public void stopServer() throws IOException
    {
        serverSocket.close();
    }
```

and the `Control` loop can be simplified like:

```
        while (true)
        {
            String key = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            switch (key)
            {
                case "close":
                    activeServer.stopServer();
                    return;
            }
        }
```