# Stop the serversocket after a client issues a command

Tags: java, networking

I have an application where a ServerSocket will accept a big number of clients and  every client will have a thread assigned. The clients will communicate with the server and if one client will send the command: "enough"  the server will stop working. The question is, how can I do this if only the thread is responsible with the client? How can a command issued by a client stop the server? Is there any way I can close the ServerSocket from the thread? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method)

Comment: Thanks I think this will help me!