# How to send a signal to a Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread currently listening to a port.

When some other threads sends signal  I want to make it listen to other port (close current socket and open other socket on a different port).

How can I do this without interrupting the Thread and creating a new one? Did some search and did not found any way of signaling a Thread that is doing some other task.

Comment: If the thread is blocking indefinetly (e.g. because it is listening on a port without a timeout), we cannot "interrupt" the thread.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method